# although I am using a background worker GUI still hanging...

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, backgroundworker

I have a GUI Where i have to import some document , but when i do using background worker, the GUI is hanging , which must not happen since I am using a background worker, why this happens? kindly find code below..

```
void ImportNotes_ContextMenuStripItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!backgroundWorker_notesImport.IsBusy)
    {
        mainFrm.ProgressBar.Visible = true;
        backgroundWorker_notesImport.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}

private void backgroundWorker_notesImport_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    ImportNotes();
}

private void backgroundWorker_notesImport_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    mainFrm.ProgressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}

void ImportNotes() { }
```

Comment: How many times are you updating the progress bar. If you take the progress bar hook out, does the hang go away?

Comment: By GUI hanging, do you mean the window won't even repaint, can't be resized, etc.?  Or do you just mean the progress bar doesn't update?

Comment: This code won't hang your GUI. You must have left out the important bit(s)

Answer (score 0):

Does the `ImportNotes()` method just do the whole import in one big step?

If so then you still aren't giving the UI chance to do anything.  The [example from the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) shows how it should be used:

```
    // This event handler is where the time-consuming work is done.
    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            if (worker.CancellationPending == true)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                // Perform a time consuming operation and report progress.
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                worker.ReportProgress(i * 10);
            }
        }
    }
```

You need to have a loop that allows some processing (the `Sleep` in this case) and a call to `ReportProgress`.